# Kaplan Meier Analysis: Survival Table to time-to-event OR directly importing summarised survival data

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Is there a way in R to create a Kaplan Meier survival curve according to an existing Survival Table (with its columns being Time (in days) - Number of survivors - Number dead - Number censored; see below)? Due to my experiment design, I only have the cumulative data. I have a few thousand "cases" I now need to analyse and I'd rather not have to type in each datapoint seperately (which would be riddled with potential mistakes).

I have the data typed in Excel, if that helps any, and have already created a KM plot with it, but I'd like to do some further analysis with it, so I'm trying to structure my data in a way that R can handle it.

Please let me know what other information you need, and thanks a ton for your help!

[this is an example how my raw data looks like]

```
Day surv    dead    censor
0   75  0   0
1   72  0   3
2   72  0   0
3   70  0   1
4   70  0   1
5   69  0   1
6   63  0   6
7   59  1   3
8   58  1   0
9   57  1   0
10  55  2   0
11  53  2   0
12  53  0   0
13  51  1   1
14  47  4   0
15  45  2   0
16  40  4   1
17  40  0   0
18  40  0   0
19  37  3   0
20  35  2   0
21  33  2   0
22  28  4   1
23  24  4   0
24  19  5   0
25  16  3   0
26  13  3   0
27  12  1   0
28  8   4   0
29  7   1   0
30  4   3   0
31  2   2   0
32  2   0   0
33  1   1   0
34  1   0   0
35  0   1   0
```